# if the big bang only expanded the universe when and how did it originate?

Tags: big-bang-theory

If the big bang expanded the universe from a singularity point, that means that there was matter before, so where and how did matter form for the first time if it's even possible to know such a thing?

Comment: @called2voyage I've searched before I asked, could you point me to the question you think is similar to mine?

Comment: The link is above: [How do we know the big bang didn't happen in an existing universe?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/how-do-we-know-the-big-bang-didnt-happen-in-an-existing-universe).

Answer (score 3):

"before" is not the right word. It suggests that there was an arrow of time which allowed to trace events. But time was created only with the big bang, there was no before.

We don't know where the matter came from, or what caused the Big Bang. One hypothesis suggests that it was caused by the collision of *branes* in other universes, but there's no way to verify this, so in a strict sense it isn't science. Many researchers think we'll never have an answer this.

Comment: But there are "A theorists of Time"