# How did the Big Bang occured if before that there was no time?

Tags: big-bang-theory, time

I am thinking, that if the Big Bang created time, it implies that before the Big Bang there was no time (correct me if I am wrong).

My question is that, if there was no time before the Big Bang, how did the Big Bang occured ?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1484/how-do-we-know-the-big-bang-didnt-happen-in-an-existing-universe

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24018/how-can-something-happen-when-time-does-not-exist

Comment: I've voting to reopen this question because the answers in the alleged duplicate don't actually answer the question.